# Select an Entity with a max value

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

First, I have a SQL table called `EstadosPorDispositivos`, with these columns:

```
EstadoPorDispositivosID (PK, Int, Auto_Increment)
DispositivoID, 
EstadoDispositivo, 
DateTimeInicio 
DateTimeFinal.
```

What I want is to retrieve an entity from that db which has a specific `ID` and has the maximum `EstadoPorDispositivosID`.

I'm at this point:

```
using (var db = new ContextoDB())
{
    var estado = db.EstadosPorDispositivos
              .Where<EstadosPorDispositivo>(e => e.DipositivoID == this.DispositivoID && ...)
    (...)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just order by that property and take the first one.
And don't forget to make your database calls async ;)

```
using (var db = new ContextoDB())
{
    var estado = await db.EstadosPorDispositivos
    .Where(e => e.DipositivoID == this.DispositivoID)
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.EstadoPorDispositivosID)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false)
}
```

Comment: _"don't forget to make your database calls async"_ - not so easy if your codebase is already synchronous.

Comment: So to get the maximum you order all elements? If you want to find `ZZ-top` in your list of bands-and-composers, it seems a waste to order `Bach` and `Beethoven`

Comment: The generated SQL query will be a `SELECT TOP(1)` and your database is smart enough to figure out, that only the maximum n (1 in this case) rows need to be returned.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Max`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
var estado = db.EstadosPorDispositivos.Where(e => e.DipositivoID == this.DispositivoID && ...)
                                      .Max(c => c.EstadoPorDispositivosID)
```

Or another way without using `Max`:

```
var estado = db.EstadosPorDispositivos.Where(e => e.DipositivoID == this.DispositivoID && ...)
                                      .OrderByDescending(t => t.EstadoPorDispositivosID)
                                      .FirstOrDefault()?.EstadoPorDispositivosID;
```

Comment: Thanks! The ? after FirstOrDefault(), what is it for?

Comment: @AgustinMeinardo The `?` will *Tests the value of the left-hand operand for null before performing a member access*. It is called null-conditional Operator https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators